# I used GParted in Ubuntu to reformat my partitions, now windows won't boot!

Tags: windows, gparted, ssd, partitioning, fat32

Let me start by saying I did clone my SSD to my old HDD so if I really did mess up, I haven't lost anything. Anyway, so I bought a new SSD a while ago and copied my old HDD over to my new SSD using Macrium, and that went off without a hitch, it worked fine. The problem was, My C: drive only had 180 gigs available, and when I went into my partitions manager it revealed that I had 280 gigs of unallocated space. Easy enough right? Just expand the main partition into the unallocated space? Well, then there was my FAT32 ESP Partition in the way, and people recommended I use GParted, via Ubuntu Pendrive linux, to move that to the end of my unallocated space then expand my main partition. So I did that and now I can't boot, it goes strait to bios WHAT DID I DO WRONG?

Comment: I would never recommend cloning a HDD to an SSD. Just do a clean install. (Not to mention that the performance will be better with a clean install as well)

Comment: UEFI recommends having ESP - efi system partition as first. But Windows often makes it second or even third, but near beginning of drive. Do not know where you would ever find instructions to make it last. UEFI uses the GUID (not UUID) of the gpt partition. So if you created a new gpt partition, you may have to update all your UEFI entries. As suggested, run Boot-Repair.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)?

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

It will automatically try some fixes for you.

Comment: Would this fix a windows boot problem? I only used used pen drive linux to use parted and then changed my windows partitions, then removed my usb and tried booting windows but it went to bios. I am still able to boot to Ubuntu on my flash drive, but that isn'y my problem.

Comment: It says it is supposed to: `Boot-Repair is a simple tool to repair frequent boot issues you may encounter in Ubuntu like... when you can't boot Windows after installing Ubuntu, or...`

Comment: Okay, I guess I'll try. So how would I do that? Boot onto my usb ubuntu and install the boot repair, then do something with the command line you sent? Sorry, I don't know much on this subject so more specific direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Yeah try booting onto the usb ubuntu and run the commands above.  The program basically has a button that says "fix", and it tries to find problems and fix them.  Of course I don't know if it will work, but it helped me when I had a similar problem.